# Пожалуйста, помогите как импортировать файл CSV

Tags: python, csv

Пожалуйста, помогите как импортировать файл CSV, может я делаю что-то не так, выдает вот такую ошибку.
[image: выдает]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код текстом (а не скриншотом), и текст ошибки полностью текстом.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете смело закомментировать строку с вызовом read_csv() по двум причинам:

1. на следующей строке вы перезаписываете переменные “X” и “y“
2. read_csv() возвращает **один** объект типа pandas.DataFrame, поэтому данная строка не может правильно отработать, т.к. вы
   пытаетесь присвоить один объект а в левой части две переменных.